# unable to get the parent collection document could firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I am working on a demo project cloning instagram.
I am storing "posts" collection by naming uid as document per user
also storing "follow" subcollection in logged user.

I want to compare subcollection "follow" data uid with postData collection Doc and access followed user posts collection
I have used code as per docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection

```
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "postData"));
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```

nothing return

Comment: As shown in your Firebase console screenshot, these documents are displayed with an italic font in the Firebase console: this is because these docs are only present (in the console) as "container" of one or more sub-collection but they are not a "genuine" document. Have a look at the duplicate answers for a solution: The easiest way is to materialize these non-existing docs (shown in italic) by creating them with a dummy field.